# Does default constructor of deque throw?

Tags: c++, stl, deque

(Assuming allocator's default constructor does not throw)

[Boost implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/boost/container/deque.hpp) of Deque says:

> Throws if allocator_type's default constructor throws

What does C++ standard specify ?

Thanks

Comment: this is a "please read the documentation for me" question. why don't you read the documentation yourself? you can download a draft of the C++ standard from the committee pages

Comment: @BoPersson: yes, about the same.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf yes, you are so very right, I should have checked the documentation myself first... I'll remember this one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++11 Standard (Paragraph 23.3.3.2) specifies:

```
explicit deque(const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

> 1 Effects: Constructs an empty deque, using the specified allocator.
>
> 2 Complexity: Constant.

That's it. No mention is made of the conditions under which this constructor may or may not throw, nor does Clause 23 (dedicated to sequence containers) specify any general exception safety guarantees, and the constructor itself is not marked as (conditionally) `noexcept`.

Therefore, one must just assume it can throw.

Answer (score 0):

`std::allocator`s requirements make its constructors `noexcept`, as it says `shall not exit via an exception`. However, the deque's constructor can throw as it is not `noexcept`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Its just that Andy replied earlier so I choose his reply as answer. :)

Comment: @shanxS: No problem, [here is a link to the latest C++ standard draft](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/tree/master/papers) so you can check yourself.